# Creating a thread to run tasks with a timeout in a Spring Webserver

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, spring-mvc

I'm trying to create a thread which runs a set of tasks and, if it does not finish within a specific time (say 100 seconds), throws an exception. Currently I am trying to do this by encapsulating the tasks into a `runnable` object and using `ExecutorService` and `Future` classes to do the timeout executions. However, when I start my Webservice I get this exception:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.localhostInterpolatorHealthCheck': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:202)
```

I read online that it's not as simple as defining your own threads and starting them to get a thread started on Spring, so I am wondering how to do this? What am I missing?

Comment: according to exception message, your task is using spring bean with request scope, while your scheduled thread execution is not in a request scope. attach the task code or describe what it is doing

Comment: @AdamSkywalker It is creating a class which extends runnable, encapsulating that class inside a thread and using `Future` and `ExecutorService` to do a time-limited code block. The code block runs a series of health tests. The new class doesn't have a bean backing it (I didn't think it was required), is this possibly where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I don't have enough information, I see that code somehow uses spring beans. Do you have a complete stacktrace? Now it shows only the top of exception.

Comment: @AdamSkywalker It is quite long. Should I send it to you via chat or something?

Comment: yes, you can use chat

Comment: based on what I see: your code in external thread wants to access request sensitive information that is available only inside a thread that handles the request. Review how your class uses spring beans, the problem is there.

Comment: @AdamSkywalker Can you elaborate? Sorry I am new to spring. `HealthCheckWorker` actually has no bean backing it, btw.

Comment: I can't guess how it works without the code.

Comment: Could you append code of localhostInterpolatorHealthCheck?

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
   /**
     * Executes a task with a specified timeout.
     */
    public final class TimeoutController {

        /**
         * Do not instantiate objects of this class. Methods are static.
         */
        private TimeoutController() {
        }

        /**
         * Executes <code>task</code>. Waits for <code>timeout</code>
         * milliseconds for the task to end and returns. If the task does not return
         * in time, the thread is interrupted and an Exception is thrown.
         * The caller should override the Thread.interrupt() method to something that
         * quickly makes the thread die or use Thread.isInterrupted().
         * @param task The thread to execute
         * @param timeout The timeout in milliseconds. 0 means to wait forever.
         * @throws TimeoutException if the timeout passes and the thread does not return.
         */
        public static void execute(Thread task, long timeout) throws TimeoutException {
            task.start();
            try {
                task.join(timeout);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                /* if somebody interrupts us he knows what he is doing */
            }
            if (task.isAlive()) {
                task.interrupt();
                throw new TimeoutException();
            }
        }

        /**
         * Executes <code>task</code> in a new deamon Thread and waits for the timeout.
         * @param task The task to execute
         * @param timeout The timeout in milliseconds. 0 means to wait forever.
         * @throws TimeoutException if the timeout passes and the thread does not return.
         */
        public static void execute(Runnable task, long timeout) throws TimeoutException {
            Thread t = new Thread(task, "Timeout guard");
            t.setDaemon(true);
            execute(t, timeout);
        }

        /**
         * Signals that the task timed out.
         */
        public static class TimeoutException extends Exception {
            /** Create an instance */
            public TimeoutException() {
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Same error: Exception in thread "Thread-25" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.localhostInterpolatorHealthCheck': Scope 'request' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found:

Comment: you are not properly define bean scopedTarget.localhostInterpolatorHealthCheck, thread cannot obtain request from this bean.

Comment: properly define your bean in your spring configuration then it works.

Comment: what do you mean by 'properly define bean'?

Answer (score 1):

You can have several @async methods instead, and then run them from your main code flow, obtain list of futures. After timeout passes you can get result or stop execution (cancel/terminate).

This has benefits as you will call spring managed beans, thus all dependency injected properties will be available for you. But you should be careful on the amount of jobs/threads you submit.

In order to use @async annotation you need to enable async stuff by using either specific line in your xml configuration or AsyncEnabled annotation on your bean.